# How to deploy an existing python package to jFrog Artifactory?

Tags: pip, artifactory

I would like the python package 'numpy' to be present at our organization Artifactory. I downloaded the package from pypi (`pip install numpy`) and now I want to upload it to Artifactory.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Are you using Artifactory to proxy pypi (via a remote repository)? this can be an easier way to get python artifacts into the organization

Comment: No, I'm using artifactory as a single source of packages, I want to upload the package directly to artifactory

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by using distutils or setuptools or Python.

You can find the relevant documentation with some examples [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/PyPI+Repositories#PyPIRepositories-PublishingtoArtifactory).